# Surface area of revolution of trig fn

Tags: definite-integrals

I want to fine the surface area of revoultion around the y-axis of
$$x=cos^3(\theta), y=sin^3(\theta)$$

I looked up a answer below but it's confusing me. (note that it's revolution around x-axis)

---

[image]

---

To find the surface area, shouldn't it be $ S=\int_{a}^{b} 2\pi y \;dx $ ? similar to disk method?

where does the $\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}$ come from? I believe it has to do with line integral and have no idea what it does here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a slice of the surface of revolution perpendicular to its axis, the shape you get will be (in the limit of an infinitely thin slice) part of a **cone**, not of a cylinder.  The area of such a shape is
$$A=\pi(r_1+r_2)\ell\ ,$$
where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the radii of the two ends and $\ell$ is the **slant height** (not the vertical or horizontal "height").  In the limit, $r_1$ and $r_2$ are both $f(x)$, and the slant height is
$$d\ell=\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}
  =\sqrt{\Bigl(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\Bigr)^2+\Bigl(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\Bigr)^2}
    d\theta\ .$$
So the area element is
$$dA=2\pi f(x)\sqrt{\Bigl(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\Bigr)^2+\Bigl(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\Bigr)^2}d\theta\ .$$

Comment: I think I got it. I'll try it myself. Thank you!

Comment: How come r1+r2 = 2f(x) instead of f(x)+f(x+dx) or y+y+dy?

Comment: In the limit as the slice becomes infinitely thin, there is no difference between $y$ and $y+dy$.

Comment: These kind of concepts always confuse me. they are sometimes the same yet sometimes different a little bit. am I going too far if I ask you why they are said to be the same?